# latex template for webpage

Tags: tex4ht

I'm looking for a latex doc template, which can be easily compiled with tex4ht for a webpage. I'm looking to create a simple (pretty much text only) personal webpage. Is anyone aware of a freely available such template?

Thanks.

Comment: How plain of a webpage? I'm not convinced this is a good idea unless it is mostly just text (and, maybe, math).

Comment: A CV-like page? It is mostly about text and links to docs or webpages. Why would that not be recommended?

Comment: A CV-like page is more reasonable. If the CV is an academic one, just design a good, readable, and relatively plain CV using one of the base document classes (e.g., `article`) and then convert it with `tex4ht`.  The more convoluted the CV, the more special `\if-` constructions you're likely going to need. Don't use a template unless you happen to see one that completely suits your academic (sub-)discipline *and* you don't mind (potentially) looking like a lot of other people.

Comment: `tex4ht` should be able to compile any LaTeX document, if not, you can post details here or on [tex4ht issue tracker](https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/projects/tex4ht/). it produces really plain documents, but it can be easily styled using CSS.